# Create a new colum with the aggregation of the sum of another colum grouped by another column - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, transform

I would like to create a new column for the follow data set which will receive the sum of the ForecastSum column grouped by each PNO row/column value:

[image]

So I would like to create a new column "ForecastPNO" for this df which will receive as example for PNO 8007205 the groouped sum by the ForecastSUM values (6 + 7 = 13) for all the rows, and consecutivaly for the others PNO values, so the order of the sum by each index should be following the order of the PNO column:
13/13/13/ 5/5/5 /9/9/9

The table with this new column should have the same numbers of index as it is in the df dataset image shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby('PNO')['ForecastSUM'].transform(sum)
```